# Unable to Deploye War file on OpenShipt

Tags: openshift

i am new to openshift.i have created a app on openshift.i want to deploy war file on this app.i have put my war file in webapps folder and remove src and pom.xml file and if i push our code then my war file not deployed on server.Still i am getting blank page on url.So please help me.

Answer (score 0):

so after removing the pom file did you add your war file to git??

```
git rm -r src pom.xml
git add deployments/Root.war
git commit
git push
```

Remember if you are using tomcat and you want your app to be deployed on / it should be named as ROOT or else if your war name is say TEST it will be available at

```
http://<app-name>-<domain-name>.rhcloud.com/TEST
```

Comment: i have add war file to webapps folder.

Comment: you need to add the war file in deployments folder

Comment: I have put this also in deployments folder but get same response i.e Not deployed.

Comment: What was the name of your war file, can u share the screenshot of your fioe directory ?